# DocumentClientException "Request size is too large"

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have created JSON that byte.length is too large, and when I try to use the api java:

```
documentClient.createDocument(
                    getTodoCollection().getSelfLink(), document, null,
                    false)
```

returns an

> DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Request size is too large"]}

Is there any way to save this kind of files in the documentDB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [`DocumentDB limits and quotas`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/) page, maximum size of a document can be <del>512 KB</del> 2 MB. If your JSON size is more than that, you will get this error.

If the size of your document is more than <del>512 KB</del> 2 MB, then you can't save the document as is in DocumentDB. One thing you could do is save the JSON in Blob Storage as a block blob and save the Blob URL in DocumentDB.

<del>P.S. For some reason I thought the size of an attachment in DocumentDB is 2 MB and I thought of suggesting that but it seems they have changed it to 512 KB as well.</del>

Comment: Another potential workaround (depending on how large your documents are expected to get) is to not serialize default values. In other words, nulls, falses, 0s, etc. do not get serialized. In my specific case this reduced our document size by about half, consistently. This was using the .NET SDK but I'm sure there's a way to not serialize defaults in Java too.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#documents
Currently, maximum size of document is 2 MB.