# RequestEntityTooLarge in cosmos stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to pass the more than 3 MB json data as input parameter to a CosmosDB stored procedure but I get an error

> RequestEntityTooLarge

Is there any limitation or there is other way to do that?

Below is the screenshot where I am just returning the constant to check there is Ru's consumption over the data param or not.

[image]

**Note**: Container RU's is set to 10k

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DocumentClientException "Request size is too large"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985331/documentclientexception-request-size-is-too-large)

Comment: Aside from this being answered in the question @Sajeetharan pointed to: just note that a container's RU/sec setting doesn't have any impact on maximum document size.

Answer (score 1):

[Hi max size for the item is 2MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-item-limits)

> Per-item limits
>
> Depending on which API you use, an Azure Cosmos item can represent either a document in a collection, a row in a table, or a node or edge in a graph. The following table shows the limits per item in Cosmos DB.
>
> Maximum size of an item:  2 MB (UTF-8 length of JSON representation)